# Bootstrap layout on lower resolution

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, grid-layout

I have the following code:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-2">
      <input style="width:100%" >
   </div>
</div>
```

And Fiddle:
[Sample](https://jsfiddle.net/3wekv1vu/1/)

On my default resolution: 1920x1080 changing number of columns (col-sm-2) will change a width of the text input. But on 1024x768 the width is always the whole column regardless of col-sm-xx setting. Can someone please explain why it's happening?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at the breakpoints for bootstrap? Your answer is right there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

BootStrap follows a simple rule ie **`MOBILE FIRST`**

It means if you just provide `col-xs-??` then this gets priority and whatever number is provided here will be provided to all above size screen unless specifically provided.

Similar is the case for `col-sm-??` hence it won't affect `xs` screen but will affect `md` and `lg` screens if those are not provided separately.

Therefore, what is happening is its just depicting the property of BootStrap.

> *CSS priority: **xs > sm > md > lg***

That is why it is advised while writing CSS

> Put media query for larger screens not for mobile screen.

Hope it answers your question.

Answer (score 3):

The bootstrap grid system is broken down into 12 columns.

12 columns represent the entire page.

The Bootstrap grid system has four classes, depending on your device size

- xs: This is used for smartphones
- sm: This is used for tablets
- md: This is used for desktops
- lg: This is used for larger desktops

It's important to note that every class scales up. For example, to use the same width for both smartphones and tablets, you would simply need a `col-xs-xx` class

In your case, `col-sm-2` represents two out of the 12 columns on a screen. In other words, it will always take up one sixth of the screen.

> Bootstrap's grid system is responsive, and the columns will re-arrange depending on the screen size: On a big screen it might look better with the content organized in three columns, but on a small screen it would be better if the content items were stacked on top of each other.

Resource

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

Comment: My question is why on lower resolution changing column setting does not make any difference.

Comment: Re-read my post. the classes scale up. `col-sm-2` will offer the same width for tablets, desktops and large desktops.

Comment: To add a note on Richard's answer, each classes has a specific breakpoint at different widths (measured in pixels). You can read more details about the grid system and breakpoints here:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-the-bootstrap-3-grid-system

Answer (score 2):

The class you're using, `col-sm-2` will take up 1/6th (2/16) of the available width **until** your window width is less than `768px wide`. More details on the breakpoints and device support here:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-the-bootstrap-3-grid-system